# Golang tree traversal order

Tags: go

Just started trying out golang, stuck at trying to figure out tree traversal exercise in the tutorial

I can't figure out how the different order of tree traversal affects the result of the golang tutorial on equivalent tree (https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/8)

Specifically... how is this...

```
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int){
    ch<-t.Value
    if t.Left != nil{
        Walk(t.Left, ch)
    }
    if t.Right != nil{
        Walk(t.Right, ch)
    }
}
```

different from this...

```
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int){

    if t.Left != nil{
        Walk(t.Left, ch)
    }
    ch<-t.Value
    if t.Right != nil{
        Walk(t.Right, ch)
    }
}
```

I would have thought both would provide the same result with the following function:

```
func Same(t1, t2 *tree.Tree) bool{
    chTree1 := make(chan int)
    chTree2 := make(chan int)

    go Walk(t1, chTree1)
    go Walk(t2, chTree2)

    for i:= 0; i < 10; i++{
        a, b := <-chTree1, <-chTree2
        //fmt.Printf("a: %v, b: %v\n", a, b)

        if a != b {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of the way `New` is implemented:

```
func New func New(k int) *Tree
```

> New returns a new, random binary tree holding the values k, 2k, ..., 10k.

Thus, while two trees created using `tree.New(1)` will have a different structure, they'll have the exact same elements.

Your second `Walk` implementation (below):

```
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int){

    if t.Left != nil{
        Walk(t.Left, ch)
    }
    ch<-t.Value
    if t.Right != nil{
        Walk(t.Right, ch)
    }
}
```

is performing an [inorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order) of the tree. An inorder traversal always returns the elements of the trees in a sorted order.

Hence, any call to this `Walk` with same value of `k` to `tree.New(k)` will result in the same list of elements, namely k, 2k, ..., 10k.

This results in this version of `Walk` always returning true.

Comment: Ah it makes sense now. Thanks a lot! Got stuck at this particular issue for a few days!